# Change root password without holding shift on grub

Tags: 14.04, grub2, permissions, sudo, root

When I hold the left shift key on grub menu, nothing appears and it still boots to Ubuntu like it normally does (Ubuntu is the only machine installed). How can I change the password for root elseway? I have access to the terminal but when I write sudo, it says that I am not a sudoer and incident will be reported. I was a suoder and used to be able sudo until today which I messed up with system. Apparently the solution is changing the root password.[image]

When I am trying to start the GUI it tells "Failed to start the session" however I used CTL+ALT+F1 and have access to terminal.

Note that I am not a sudoer and cannot change grub settings.

Comment: Do you know the current root password? Is it set or not? There is a difference if you want to change a known or unknown root password. For known root password type `su` and you will get root privileges if you know root password. If you don't know it, you should boot from a USB or CD/DVD, mount the Ubuntu partition and change the password.

Comment: I am not sure "Failed to start the session" is linked to sudoers. You must have messed something else too.

Comment: The error "Failed to start session" existed before I mess up with the sudoers list and remove myself and everyone else in our group as a sudoer.

Comment: Boot from live CD or USB, mount your root partition and fix the sudoers file

Comment: From the answers to the linked question use one of the methods that don't rely on the recovery mode .

Comment: This is probably not a duplicate (of the missing password) --there is no root password, unless you set it, which is discouraged.  Do you know the bad changes or have a working /etc/sudoers file?  Does your sudoers file have the line "%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL".   Is your username still on the /etc/group line sudo? Use the above mentioned CD/USB boot to fix things.